# Amplify Delete - React Native

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

Is there any way deleting an amplify for pulled project. I've pulled a test project from github that I foound in a tutorial but it has amplify project. I wanted to use that project to practice aws amplify. This is the error that I kept Getting when I run AMPLIFY DELETE --->
Error occurred while deleting× Project delete failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just delete root `amplify` folder from your code. Since the `Amplify` backend is not created on your AWS account, `amplify delete` will fail.